# Unauthorized LDAP user to deploy in a Nexus repository

Tags: active-directory, ldap, nexus

I can't deploy a maven project with a LDAP user, but I can deploy this project with the Nexus user "deployment". I create a external role mapping and add the same privileges of Nexus user "deployment", but the result always is:

*Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.*

I use Nexus 2.11.4 and Maven 3.2.5. I config the deploy with the settings.xml and other configurations in the pom.xml. I don't think the problem is there, because I deploy projects using the user "deployment". But, the LDAP user fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, the solution is on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34090851/cant-apply-roles-effectively-on-sonatype-nexus-with-active-directory-users/34093121) and [here](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/ldap-sect-enabling.html)

Basycally is going to the left menu, to Administration > Server > Security Settings and move the "OSD LDAP Authentication Realm" to the left (alongside XML Authentication Realm and XML Authorizing Realm).